# mcq the value of the following integral $ \int_{0}^{1}\ln(1+x^{2})dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

the value of the following integral $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(1+x^{2}\right)dx $ is :

1. $\ln(2)+\dfrac{\pi}{2} $
2. $\ln(2)-2+\dfrac{\pi}{2} $
3. $\ln(2)+2-\dfrac{\pi}{2} $

Let

- $u(x)=\ln(1+x^{2})$ then $u'(x)=\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}$
- $v'(x)=1$ then $v(x)=x $

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(1+x^{2}\right)dx=x\ln(1+x^{2})\bigg|_{0}^{1}-2\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{2x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}dx=\ln(2)-2-2\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{1+x^{2}}dx  $$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i'm stuck i don't know how to get to the right answer

Comment: The last integrand relates to a well-known function.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  arctan(x)

Comment: @Cyro: then you have it.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't wantto get an exact evaluation of the integral but just want to choose the correct answer:

Drawing a picture to see what the value of your integral might be tells you that $$\int_0^1\ln(1+x^2)dx<\frac12,$$

implying that (1) and (3) can't be solutions since each is bigger than $\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \tan^{-1}x + C$$

To derive this, use $x=\tan\theta$, $dx = \sec^2\theta d\theta$ and $1+\tan^2\theta = \sec^2\theta$.

$$\int_{0}^{1}\ln(1+x^2)dx = x\ln(1+x^2)\bigg\vert_{x=0}^{x=1} - \int_{0}^{1}\frac{2x^2dx}{1+x^2} = \ln(2) - 2 + 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx \\\\ = \ln(2) - 2 +2\pi/4 = \ln(2) - 2 + \pi/2$$

Comment: how can i get that integral

Comment: Put $x=\tan\theta$, $dx = \sec^2\theta d\theta$ and $1+\tan^2\theta = \sec^2\theta$

Comment: by using $\int \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \tan^{-1}x + C$ how can i get $\pm \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ to know which answer is correct in mcq question

Comment: Put the limits. $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \tan^{-1}(1) - \tan^{-1}(0) = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: could you elaborate more in your answer beside the  three porposed answers doesn't contain $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Check edit. But I discourage complete solutions for easy questions.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(1+x^{2}\right)dx$$

$$=x\ln(1+x^2)\bigg|_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2x^2}{1+x^2}dx$$

$$=\ln 2-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2x^2+2-2}{1+x^2}dx$$

$$=\ln 2-\int_{0}^{1}[2-\frac{2}{1+x^2}]dx$$

$$=\ln 2-2+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2}{1+x^2}dx$$
By letting $x=\tan\theta,$
$$=\ln 2-2+\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{2\sec^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}d\theta$$

$$=\ln 2-2+\int_{0}^{\pi/4}2d\theta$$

$$=\ln 2-2+\frac{\pi}{2}$$